# UI automator dumps "Killed"

Tags: android, adb, ui-automation, android-uiautomator

`./adb exec-out uiautomator dump /dev/tty` returns the output `Killed` repeatedly. Incidentally, sometimes it does return the xml file. What is the remedy for it?

Answer (score 1):

I encounter this while running tests with UIAutomator. Once my integration tests stop, `uiautomator dump` starts working again.

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar problem. I'm not sure why it is like this. But each time after I try `uiautomator help` and `uiautomator events`, It can work again.
This is quite strange, but it do work for me. I hope it will work for you too

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue while I connected Android 12.
What is the solution after restarting the device it is working.

Restart the device using,

```
`adb reboot`
```

What I have given

```
`adb shell uiautomator dump`
```

What it returns

```
>>>`UI hierchary dumped to: /sdcard/window_dump.xml`
```